# Fill Excel field with future date when checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following to insert today's date into an excel cell after a checkbox is checked. I want to change it so it inserts the date of the upcoming Sunday. I tried using the Weekday function but can't get the syntax right or this isn't the right approach. Can you help?

```
Sub Process_CheckBox()

   Dim cBox As CheckBox
   Dim LRow As Integer
   Dim LRange As String

   LName = Application.Caller
   Set cBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(LName)

   'Find row that checkbox resides in
   LRow = cBox.TopLeftCell.Row
   LRange = "D" & CStr(LRow)

   'Change date in column D, if checkbox is checked
   If cBox.Value > 0 Then
      ActiveSheet.Range(LRange).Value = Date

   'Clear date in column D, if checkbox is unchecked
   Else
      ActiveSheet.Range(LRange).Value = Null
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `date + 7 - WEEKDAY(Date)+ 1`

To understand what is going with the formula, it is probably better to represent it as `date-WEEKDAY(date)+1+7`.

From the current date you are subtracting the # for the day of the week representing that date which gives you the date of the last day of the previous week. You then add 1 day to get the first day of the current week (this Sunday) and then add another 7 days to get Next Sunday.

Like wise you would use `date-WEEKDAY(date)+2+7` for next Monday, `date-WEEKDAY(date)+3` for next Tuesday and so on.

Comment: The code worked like a charm! Now when I check the box it inserts the next Sunday just like I needed it to. Thank you!